Converting nested YAML to Turtle
I have a database in YAML format, which describes translations into Yiddish. Here is an example entry:
id: ytd000643
slug: Der_Golem_Zilburg
title: דער גולם
title_translit: Der Golem
translator:
  - name:
    name_translit: Zilburg, M.
    wikidata: null
editions:
  - type: book
    title: דער גולם
    title_translit: Der Golem
    publisher: null
    publisher_translit: B. Kletskin
    place: Vilne
    year: 1925
    volumes:
      - number: no volume
        date:
        first_page:
        last_page:
        source: nybc
        source_id: nybc212177
        notes:
    notes:
keywords: []
notes:
source:
  - ytds000605

I am trying to figure out how to convert this into triples in order to publish it as Linked Open Data. The first layer of keys (id, slug, title, etc.) seems easy enough, but I don't understand what to do with the translator, editions, and volumes arrays. Is there a way to represent this as is in Turtle? Or do I need to make, for example, separate id's for translator, editions, and volumes, and reference those instead? Or is perhaps RDF/XML a better format for this? Any guidance would be appreciated!

Ideally, each relevant thing gets its own RDF instance. A thing could be anything. To identify the relevant ones, a good approach can be to think about whether you (or someone else) have (or could have) something to say about this thing.
In your example, such things could be:

work
translator
edition + publisher + place
volume + source
source

Turtle example for linking the translator of a work:
PREFIX :       <https://example.com/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>

:Work_ytd000643 
  a schema:CreativeWork ;
  schema:translator :Person_42 .

:Person_42 
  a schema:Person ;
  schema:name "M. Zilburg" .

If a thing already has an IRI defined somewhere, e.g., in Wikidata, it would be a good practice to reuse that IRI instead of creating your own.
If you don’t have a unique identifier for a thing (e.g., because you only have the name of the translator, but different translators could have the same name), you can use a blank node:
PREFIX :       <https://example.com/>
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>

:Work_ytd000643 
  a schema:CreativeWork ;
  schema:translator [
    a schema:Person ;
    schema:name "M. Zilburg"
  ] .

The model Functional Requirements for Bibliographic Records might be relevant for your case. See the ontologies Expression of Core FRBR Concepts in RDF and Expression of Extended FRBR Concepts in RDF (see also for OWL 2 DL).

Or is perhaps RDF/XML a better format for this?

For your case, it doesn’t matter whether you use Turtle, RDF/XML, or any other RDF serialization. They can express the same, and you can convert between them.
Turtle is typically recommended, because it’s easy for humans to read/write.
